# Modifying JSON elements

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON called `rawdata` in my JS script that I need to manipulate. Specifically I need to change the `year` attribute of the second half of the `features` from `year: 1718` values to `year: 1819`. The current JSON looks like:

```
{
    features: [
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464477, uniqueid: 14494171801, property_no: 14494, year: 1718, path: "Business||CBD Works", …}},
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464478, uniqueid: 14494171802, property_no: 14494, year: 1718, path: "Roads & Bins||Roading", …}},
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464480, uniqueid: 14494171804, property_no: 14494, year: 1718, path: "Parks & Recr||Parks & Bldg", …}},
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464481, uniqueid: 14494171806, property_no: 14494, year: 1718, path: "General||Earthquake", …}}
    ]
}
```

I want it to look like:

```
{
    features: [
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464477, uniqueid: 14494171801, property_no: 14494, year: 1718, path: "Business||CBD Works", …}},
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464478, uniqueid: 14494171802, property_no: 14494, year: 1718, path: "Roads & Bins||Roading", …}},
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464480, uniqueid: 14494171804, property_no: 14494, year: 1819, path: "Parks & Recr||Parks & Bldg", …}},
            {attributes:{OBJECTID: 464481, uniqueid: 14494171806, property_no: 14494, year: 1819, path: "General||Earthquake", …}}
    ]
}
```

Note that this is a subset of the data (hence why I don't just manually change it.

I have only managed to change all of the `year` values to `1819` and/or created a recursive function due to the push-ing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this. The array `features` within the `JSON.parse`'d variable can be iterated.

```js
var x = '{"Name": "Worm","features":[{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":464477,"uniqueid":14494171801,"property_no":14494,"year":1718,"path":"Business||CBD Works"}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":464478,"uniqueid":14494171802,"property_no":14494,"year":1718,"path":"Roads & Bins||Roading"}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":464480,"uniqueid":14494171804,"property_no":14494,"year":1718,"path":"Parks & Recr||Parks & Bldg"}},{"attributes":{"OBJECTID":464481,"uniqueid":14494171806,"property_no":14494,"year":1718,"path":"General||Earthquake"}}]}'

var rawdata = JSON.parse(x);
console.log("Input: ");
console.log(rawdata);

for (var i = 0; i < rawdata.features.length; ++i) {
  if (i >= (rawdata.features.length/2)) {
   rawdata.features[i].attributes.year = 1920;
  }

}
console.log("Output: ");
console.log(rawdata);
```